# Jenkins - How do I publish coverage report to github

Tags: java, git, github, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to use [github-pr-coverage-status-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-pr-coverage-status-plugin), the documentation says I need to run the following on my master branch:

> step([$class: 'MasterCoverageAction'])

But when I add this to my pipeline I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't find GIT_URL or CHANGE_URL in envs: {BRANCH_NAME=master, BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME=#41, BUILD_ID=41, BUILD_NUMBER=41, BUILD_TAG=jenkins-testci-master-41, BUILD_URL=https://jnkns-ci.myserver.com/job/testci/job/master/41/, CLASSPATH=, HUDSON_HOME=/var/jenkins_home, HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE=01f6aedeea333d1f, HUDSON_URL=https://jnkns-ci.myserver.com/, JENKINS_HOME=/var/jenkins_home, JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=01f6aedeea333d1f, JENKINS_URL=https://jnkns-ci.myserver.com/, JOB_BASE_NAME=master, JOB_DISPLAY_URL=https://jnkns-ci.myserver.com/job/testci/job/master/display/redirect, JOB_NAME=testci/master, JOB_URL=https://jnkns-ci.myserver.com/job/testci/job/master/, RUN_CHANGES_DISPLAY_URL=https://jnkns-ci.myserver.com/job/testci/job/master/41/display/redirect?page=changes, RUN_DISPLAY_URL=https://jnkns-ci.myserver.com/job/testci/job/master/41/display/redirect}
    at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.PrIdAndUrlUtils.getGitUrl(PrIdAndUrlUtils.java:85)
    at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.MasterCoverageAction.perform(MasterCoverageAction.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:67)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:49)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:260)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have tried multiple ways to inject these variables. In my latest try, I even looked at the [source code for this class](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-pr-coverage-status-plugin/blob/44120e8cfbade4ba0737823c9b46b12744dafbf3/src/main/java/com/github/terma/jenkins/githubprcoveragestatus/PrIdAndUrlUtils.java#L80), so I changed my pipeline to be:

```
pipeline {

  agent any

  options {
    skipDefaultCheckout()
  }
  environment {
    // calling credentials() actually sets 3 environment variables
    // GIT_HUB with  <username>:<password>
    // GIT_HUB_USER with <username>
    // GIT_HUB_PSW with <password>

    GIT_HUB = credentials('tmhjenkins')
    DOCKER_REPO  = 'mobilityhouse'
    DOCKER_HUB   = credentials('tmhitadmin')
    GIT_URL_PROPERTY = "https://$GIT_HUB@github.com/mobilityhouse/testci.git"
  }

  stages{
    ...
    ...
stage('Coverage & Tests') {
      steps {
        sh 'pip3 install -e .'
        sh 'make coverage-xml'
        script {
          currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
          sh(script: 'export GIT_URL_PROPERTY="https://$GIT_HUB@github.com/mobilityhouse/testci.git"')
          env.GIT_URL_PROPERTY = "https://$GIT_HUB@github.com/mobilityhouse/testci.git"
          step([$class: 'MasterCoverageAction'])
        }
      }
    }

...
```

}

Alas, this fails too. So how am I supposed to properly use this plugin from within the pipeline? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After beating around the bush for a while, I decided to take a deeper look what this Jenkins plugin does (an [issue report in github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-pr-coverage-status-plugin/issues/39) wasn't yielding much ...)

It turned out that the master coverage reports are stored properly for example with the environment variable properly set:

```
  step([$class: 'MasterCoverageAction',
              scmVars:
                [GIT_URL:
                 "https://github.com/xxx/testci.git",]
            ])
```

This would have added an entry in the XML log file in `JENKINS_HOME`, how ever the plugin would complain:

```
Can't find master coverage repository: https://github.com/xxx/testci/pull/8 in stored: {https://github.com/myorga/testci/pull/5=0.6923, https://github.com/xxx/testci/pull/6=0.6923, https://****@github.com/myorga/testci.git=0.5385, https://github.com/xxx/testci/pull/7=0.5385}
```

This lit a red light, so I dug into the code and found the problem. Which is that the PR is detected by the plugin as: `https://github.com/xxx/testci/pull/6` however master coverage action should have only saved `https://github.com/xxx/testci` so the key is not found in the configuration file (which is parsed to a hash map). After reading through the code, it was pretty easy to fix the code.

In `githubprcoveragestatus/CompareCoverageAction.java` I replaced:

```
final float masterCoverage = masterCoverageRepository.get(gitUrl);
```

with the following lines to

```
float masterCoverage;
if (gitUrl.contains("pull/")) {
    final String myCorrectURL = "https://github.com/" + GitUtils.getUserRepo(gitUrl);
    // Using  masterCoverageRepository.get(myCorrectURL); is failing because URL is
    // https://github.com/USER/REPO/pull/PR_ID
    buildLog.println(BUILD_LOG_PREFIX + "myCorrectURL:" + myCorrectURL);
    masterCoverage = masterCoverageRepository.get(myCorrectURL);
} else {
    masterCoverage = masterCoverageRepository.get(gitUrl);
}
```

This solved my problem, in the good spirit of open source, I made a pull request to [fix how a URL for Pull Request is detected](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-pr-coverage-status-plugin/pull/43/commits/a49a2e8fd4ac1946011c5cffa4b0e84ca9cca75f), such that others can benefit from this fix.